# Find the driver of a USB device on darwin

Tags: macos, usb, iokit, darwin, kernel-extension

I am facing [this](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/158) issue on mac OS X 10.11 -- ie. some kext has taken over my device and I can't claim it with `libusb`. Is it possible to find out which one? Here is the device in question:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
[...]
        mEDBG CMSIS-DAP:

          Product ID: 0x2145
          Vendor ID: 0x03eb  (Atmel Corporation)
          Version: 10.00
          Serial Number: ATML2323040200017792
          Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: ATMEL
          Location ID: 0x14130000 / 13
          Current Available (mA): 1000
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Answer (score 6):

The user friendliest way is probably to use Apple's IORegistryExplorer app. (or the open source clone, IOJones) You'll find IORegistryExplorer in the "Hardware Tools" download in the "more downloads" section of Apple's developer site. (Free login required.) You can find your device's `IOUSBDevice` and possibly `IOUSBInterface` device objects in the service tree, and see what client objects have been created by the driver that claimed it. Those objects should have a `CFBundleIdentifier` property which will identify the kext responsible.

You can also do this with the command-line `ioreg` utility. A good starting point will be the command `ioreg -irc IOUSBHostDevice`, which shows all USB devices and their clients. (For OS X 10.10 and older, use `IOUSBDevice`.)